# Component Renders Data only if I Change Text In The IDE Code (React Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, use-effect

In Short, when I load the page, no data is rendered in the charts or table. but once I change any text in the IDE it renders the data. I have no idea why. I think I am using the useEffect hook wrong.

I think what is happening that is on component render, it renders the tables then fetches the data from Firebase afterwards but then it does not update the data within the page?

```
export default function Dashboard() {

  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [myDoubleArray, setMyDoubleArray] = useState([]);

  const [feedbackPositiveState, setFeedbackPositiveState] = useState("");
  const [feedbackNegativeState, setFeedbackNegativeState] = useState("");
  const [feedbackNeutralState, setFeedbackNeutralState] = useState("");

 // const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  var feedbackPositive = 0;
  var feedbackNegative = 0;
  var feedbackNeutral = 0;
  var data = [];
  var myArray = [
    [],
    [], // two arrays
  ];

 useEffect(() => {
    onValue(ref(db), (snapshot) => {
      setTodos([]);
      const data = snapshot.child("GlobalFeedback").val();

      console.log(data);

      if (data !== null) {
        console.log("Data is not null");

        Object.values(data).map((todo) => {
          setTodos((oldArray) => [...oldArray, todo]);
        });
      }
    });

    todos.map((items) => {
      data.push(items);
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      myArray[i] = data[i].split("|");

      //console.log(myArray[i][0]);

      if (myArray[i][0] === "Positive ") {
        feedbackPositive++;
        // console.log("Positive has been evaluated");
      }
      if (myArray[i][0] === "Neutral ") {
        feedbackNeutral++;
        //console.log("Neutral has been evaluated");
      }
      if (myArray[i][0] === "Bad ") {
        feedbackNegative++;
        // console.log("Negative has been evaluated");
      }
      // console.log(feedbackPositive);
    }
    setMyDoubleArray(myArray);
    setFeedbackPositiveState(feedbackPositive);
    setFeedbackNeutralState(feedbackNeutral);
    setFeedbackNegativeState(feedbackNegative);
  }, []);

  console.table (myDoubleArray);
  

  //console.log("positive state: " + feedbackPositiveState);
  //const database = firebase.firestore.getDatabase();
  const datasetTotal = {
    labels: ["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          feedbackPositiveState,
          feedbackNeutralState,
          feedbackNegativeState,
        ],
        backgroundColor: ["#00D788", "#F5E200", "#FF2257"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#00D788", "#F5E200", "#FF2257"],
      },
    ],
    text: "43%",
  };

  const datasetTillCashier = {
    labels: "none"[("Positive", "Neutral", "Negative")],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          feedbackPositiveState,
          feedbackNeutralState,
          feedbackNegativeState,
        ],
        backgroundColor: ["#00D788", "#F5E200", "#FF2257"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#00D788", "#F5E200", "#FF2257"],
      },
    ],
    text: "43%",
  };

  return (
    <div className="dashboardBackground">
      <h1>Dashboards: </h1>

    
      <Tabs>
        <div label="Performance"></div>
        <div label="View Settings"></div>
      </Tabs>
      <h3>All Reviewss</h3>
      <Doughnut className="doughnutDashboardTotal" data={datasetTotal} />
      <h3>Per Till Per Cashier</h3>
      <div className="pertillpercashierDiv">
        <div>
          <Doughnut
            className="pertillpercashierdoughnut"
            data={datasetTillCashier}
          />
          <h4>Cashier 1</h4>
          <h5>Till 1</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Doughnut
            className="pertillpercashierdoughnut"
            data={datasetTillCashier}
          />
          <h4>Cashiers 2</h4>
          <h5>Till 1</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Doughnut
            className="pertillpercashierdoughnut"
            data={datasetTillCashier}
          />
          <h4>Cashier 3</h4>
          <h5>Till 2</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Doughnut
            className="pertillpercashierdoughnut"
            data={datasetTillCashier}
          />
          <h4>Cashier 4</h4>
          <h5>Till 2</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Doughnut
            className="pertillpercashierdoughnut"
            data={datasetTillCashier}
          />
          <h4>Cashier 5</h4>
          <h5>Till 3</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Doughnut
            className="pertillpercashierdoughnut"
            data={datasetTillCashier}
          />
          <h4>Cashier 6</h4>
          <h5>Till 3</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h1>Raw Data</h1>
      <table>
        {myDoubleArray.map((items) => {

         
    
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{items[0]}</td>
              <td>{items[1]}</td>
              <td>{items[2]}</td>
              <td>{items[3]}</td>
              <td>{items[4]}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked to closely at your code but it sounds like you haven't accounted for the fact that setting state is asynchronous. When you call `setTodos()`, the change does not happen immediately. Multiple calls are batched together and executed at some time in the future. You're also using .map() instead of .forEach(), which is bad practice.

Comment: @ChrisG Would it be possible to set states in a non asynchronous way? that might fix my problem

Comment: No, if you want to do something after a state update, you have to put it in a useEffect callback and put the state in the dependency array. Keep in mind that you mustn't create an infinite update loop though.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the help. I created an Infinite update loop by putting the ``` myArray ``` into the dependency array. What should i put there instead to avoid this?